# Rendering partials with Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

So I have a page with a div that holds all the content as I go through the nav, like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="sidebar"></div>
 <div id="content"><div>
</div>
```

Since nothing changes except the #content I'd like to know if I can make Turbolinks only replace the content of the #content div, instead of the whole  as it does by default.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [shopifys turbograft](https://github.com/Shopify/turbograft) for this!